# How to test for success and redirect web page after product added in opencart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart

I'm using the following form to add a product to the opencart shopping cart. The problem I'm having is that after the product adds it doesn't redirect to the shopping cart but just shows a page with a product successfully added notification.

here's the form:

```
<form action="purchase/?route=checkout/cart/add" id="addToCartForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="40">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity_field" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value=>

<input type="submit" alt="Order Now" title="order now" value="Order Now test">
</form>
```

and the javascript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#addToCartForm input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'
            data: 'product_id=' + $('form#addToCartForm input[name="product_id"]').val() + '&quantity=' + $('form#addToCartForm input[name="quantity"]').val(),
            success: function(json) {
                window.location = 'purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                console.log('add success');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

after the form is clicked the page redirects to `http://*****/purchase/?route=checkout/cart/add` and the page message reads "{"success":"Success: You have added Product Name</a> to your shopping cart</a>!","total":"4 item(s) - \u00a64.40"}"

So, it does add a product, but the redirect upon 'success' doesn't seem to do anything.

the javascript console doesn't output anything with `console.log('add success');` (or it moves to the shopping cart add page too quickly to see)

thanks for any help

Comment: One question, do You know what jQuery is? Are You sure You have jQuery linked to Your website? Because now it looks like the the jQuery code is not performed and You are being submitted to the form's action by normal submit (not the AJAX)...

Comment: @shadyyx I have jQuery link in the <head></head> using <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.js" ></script>
is that enough? thank you

Comment: Yes, that should be enough... The jQuery code in the question above (that You have from my answer to Your previous question) looks fine and should be working...but somehow it is not... If after You click on submit and You see the page is loading and then the JSON response is displayed this means that the form is being submitted the normal way and the jQuery code has no effect... Try the @ChetanPaliwal's modification below (with catching the `.submit` on the form), this may work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `action` attribute from form, its not required (and may cause confusion in debugging)

and then use following javascript

```
$('form#addToCartForm').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'
    data: 'product_id=' + $('form#addToCartForm input[name="product_id"]').val() + '&quantity=' + $('form#addToCartForm input[name="quantity"]').val(),
    success: function (json) {
        window.location = 'purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart';
        console.log('add success');
    }

});
});
```

in your question part of your ajax requested is commented out, is it really the case or it just got commented while posting to SO ?

Comment: thanks. i tried your code and it seems like after removing the action attribute from the form it no longer moves to the http://***.co.uk/purchase/?route=checkout/cart/add page and instead stays on the original page.

Comment: @user2588945 so its all working now or not? try removing redirection and just `console.log(json)` in success function also add add error function in ajax if nothing happens with console.log and then print error

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the element with ID 'personalVirtualPrivateServerForm' is from, but clicking a button doesn't necessarily allow you to perform the e.preventDefault() you are attempting.

In your case, you are essentially saying, on click of the button perform an action, but you want to say something like:

```
$('form#addToCartForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    .... (rest of code here) ....
});
```

Basically, your form is submitting before you have a chance to redirect, when you want to stop the form submission and then send it via your $.ajax submit.  That should allow your success callback to execute.

Comment: thanks! it should be "addToCartForm" I changed "personalVirtualPrivateServerForm" to that. it was a typo